# Is it possible to use setOnMarkerClickListener to have different results to various markers created in a for loop?

Tags: java, android, image, android-intent

I'm creating an android application that displays all the photos taken with the camera at their locations on a map using markers. When one of these markers is clicked, I want the image to open in the Google photos/ gallery app.

Here is my function for adding markers:

```
public void showMarkers(){
    //getCameraImages gets all filepaths for images taken by camera
    List imagePaths = getCameraImages(this);

    // Gives the LatLng values converted from exif data
    List realLatLngs = getLatLong(imagePaths);

    for(int i = 0; i<realLatLngs.size(); i++){
        String stringLatlng = (String) realLatLngs.get(i);

        String[] latandlong = stringLatlng.split(",");
        double latitude = Double.parseDouble(latandlong[0]);
        double longitude = Double.parseDouble(latandlong[1]);

        LatLng imageLocation = new LatLng(latitude,longitude);

        String imagePath = (String) imagePaths.get(i);
        String imageName = imagePath.replace("/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/", "");

        Bitmap icon = decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(imagePath, 100, 100);

        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
        .position(imageLocation)
        .title(imageName)
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(icon));
        mMap.addMarker(options);
    }
}
```

Can I use `setonMarkerClickListener` to open the selected image (marker) using an intent like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + "/sdcard/test.jpg"), "image/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can achieve this with tag.

**Solution :**

```
String imageName = imagePath.replace("/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/", "");

MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
    .position(imageLocation)
    .title(imageName)
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(icon));
Marker marker=    mMap.addMarker(options);
 //set your image path as tag of marger
 marker.setTag(imageName);

//map marker click listener
 googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(marker -> {
        if (marker.getTag() != null) {
            String imagePath = (String) marker.getTag();
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(imagePath), "image/*");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: I'm getting the error 'Cannot resolve method 'setTag(java.lang.String)' on setTag, and 'Variable 'imagePath' is already defined in the scope' on the line                     String imagePath = (String) marker.getTag();

Comment: I've fixed those errors, however lambda expressions are not allowed in Android Studio

Comment: compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    } add this in your gradle lambda will enable

Comment: The gradle sync fails with the error 'Error:(21, 0) Could not find method compileOptions() for arguments [build_bspb982vahaapx57m5u1s31xb$_run_closure1@53fa1a37] on root project 'MemoryMap2' of type org.gradle.api.Project.'
Would you like me to post my gradle so you can check it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168456/discussion-between-rajasekaran-m-and-joe-obrien).